# Drag & Drop Component Suite: Drop files and if path isn't exists get data from file

Tags: file, delphi, drag-and-drop

I use the [Drag and Drop Component Suite](https://github.com/landrix/The-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite-for-Delphi) for Delphi.

I try to create a drag & drop area which accepts files (ie, from Windows Explorer) and data (ie, from Outlook attachments). So, I use the demo (CombatTargetDemo) to learn how it works, and after this I create a wrapper class which creates a `TDropComboTarget` object:

```pascal
constructor TDragAndDrop.Create( vpntOwner: TWinControl);
begin  
  fpntDragAndDrop                 := TDropComboTarget.Create(vpntOwner);
  fpntDragAndDrop.Name            := 'DropComboTarget_'+vpntOwner.Name;
  fpntDragAndDrop.DragTypes       := [dtCopy, dtLink];
  fpntDragAndDrop.OnDrop          := DropFiles;
  fpntDragAndDrop.Target          := vpntOwner;
  fpntDragAndDrop.Formats         := [mfFile, mfData];
end;

procedure TDragAndDrop.DropFiles(Sender: TObject; ShiftState: TShiftState; Point: TPoint; var Effect: Integer);
var
  intCnt: Integer;
  pntStream: TStream;
  strFileName: String;
  strDragAndDropFile: String;
begin
  try
    fstlDroppedFilePaths.Clear;
    fstlDroppedFilePaths.Assign(fpntDragAndDrop.Files);

    for intCnt := 0 to fpntDragAndDrop.Data.Count-1 do begin
      strFileName := fpntDragAndDrop.Data.Names[intCnt];
      if (strFileName = '') then begin
        strFileName := IntToStr(intCnt)+'_'+FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnss', Now())+'.dat';
      end;

      strDragAndDropFile := GetDragAndDropSavePath+strFileName;
      pntStream := TFileStream.Create(strDragAndDropFile, fmCreate);
      try
        pntStream.CopyFrom(fpntDragAndDrop.Data[intCnt], fpntDragAndDrop.Data[intCnt].Size);
      finally
        pntStream.Free;
      end;
      if FileExists(strDragAndDropFile, false) then begin
        fstlDroppedFilePaths.Add(strDragAndDropFile);
      end;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

First of all, the code works.

If I drop a Windows Explorer file on the area:

- `fpntDragAndDrop.Files.Count` is 1 (contains the path+name from file)
- `fpntDragAndDrop.Data.Count` is 1 (contains the file as a stream)

If I drop a file from Outlook on the area:

- `fpntDragAndDrop.Files.Count` is 0 (contains nothing)
- `fpntDragAndDrop.Data.Count` is 1 (contains the file as a stream)

Now my problem:

If I drop very large files from Windows Explorer, the component does the following:

1. Read the file header and add an item to `fpntDragAndDrop.Files`
2. Create a `TMemoryStream` and try to load the data from the file into the stream

Step 1 is perfect, but on step 2 I get an exception because of insufficient memory.

My solution:

I want that the component does Step 1. If Step 1 gives a result, then the component should skip Step 2. After this, the variables in the `DropFiles` procedure should have the following values:

If I drop a Windows Explorer file on the area:

- `fpntDragAndDrop.Files.Count` is 1 (contaims the path+name from the file)
- `fpntDragAndDrop.Data.Count` is 0 (No memory stream is loaded)

If I drop a file from Outlook on the area:

- `fpntDragAndDrop.Files.Count` is 0 (comtains nothing)
- `fpntDragAndDrop.Data.Count` is 1 (contains the file as a stream)

Does somebody have an idea? Or maybe the component has a setting for that?

Comment: *"Does somebody have an idea?"* Maybe look at the source and modify it if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with this suite, but just browsing through its source, I think you can use the `OnAcceptFormat` event to reject formats you don't want on a per-drop basis.

So, even though you have enabled drops of `mfData` doesn't mean you have to actually accept a dropped stream (`TDataStreamDataFormat`) if a file path (`TFileDataFormat` or `TFileMapDataFormat`) is available. So, query the `fpntDragAndDrop.DataObject` to see what formats it actually holds, such as by passing it to the `HasValidFormats()` method of the various formats in the `fpntDragAndDrop.DataFormats` property.

For example:

```pascal
fpntDragAndDrop.OnAcceptFormat := AcceptStreams;

...

procedure TDragAndDrop.AcceptStreams(Sender: TObject;
  const DataFormat: TCustomDataFormat; var Accept: boolean);
var
  Fmt: TCustomDataFormat;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if DataFormat is TDataStreamDataFormat then
  begin
    // FYI, TFileDataFormat should be in DataFormats[0],
    // and TFileMapDataFormat should be in DataFormats[5],
    // if you want to avoid this loop...
    for i := 0 to fpntDragAndDrop.DataFormats.Count-1 do
    begin
      Fmt := fpntDragAndDrop.DataFormats[i];
      if (Fmt <> DataFormat) and ((Fmt is TFileDataFormat) or (Fmt is TFileMapDataFormat)) then
      begin
        if Fmt.HasValidFormats(fpntDragAndDrop.DataObject) then
        begin
          Accept := False;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Accept := True; // should already be True by default...
end;
```